# separate apple IDs on same email address

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, itunes-store

our two kids have got ipod touches for Christmas.  I tried to get them separate Apple ID accounts but it said because we had the same email address we could only have the one Apple ID.  Is there a way to have two separate Apple IDs on the same email address?  If not how is the best way to keep their itunes card money separate?

Comment: I use one apple ID, that way the kids only have to purchase an app once: all ipods get it. Their money goes further. I simply keep track of iTunes gift card $$ manually, on a piece of paper. (who bought what)

Answer (score 4):

No - an Apple ID is a unique string, so you can't enter the same letters for two as the first reserves that "email" and prevents a second account.

You can have alases in one email account so that mails to more than one address get delivered to the same account. Google allows this with punctuation and arbitrary letters after a + in the email name. You can also enter punctuation like periods so if your email is RobynWhatever, mail to Robyn.Whatever also gets delivered to the first gmail account.

The only way is to have separate email account, you cannot use the same email for different account.

If I understand correctly, you want to have control over those accounts and receive the monthly purchased email in one account. You can setup 2 email accounts with forwarding service which will send all the mail from their account to your main email account.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes accounts are tied to an Apple ID so if you want to keep their accounts separate you'll need two IDs. And as IDs are not allowed to have the same email address you'll need separate ones there as well.

Options:

- set app free email addresses for them (e.g. on Gmail) and set auto-forwarding to your account
- create aliases for your iCloud account and use these
- create individual iCloud addresses for them and set auto-forwarding there

Thinking ahead I would recommend the third option. In a few years they will want/need their own mail address anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple Apple IDs connected to a single Gmail account, because Google lets you insert dots (and maybe other characters, not sure) between letters in the account name. Apple doesn’t recognize aa@gmail.com and a.a@gmail.com as being the same email address but Google does, so you can sign up for a separate ID using each of them and (assuming you own that particular gmail address) now you have two IDs which both use the same inbox for validation and account purposes. Repeat as needed.